# Matlab - sort by absolute value

Tags: sorting, matlab

How do I sort a vector in matlab by absolute value?

Answer (score 9):

Use the second output of [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) to get the order, then sort the initial array:

```
a = [-2 1 3 -1.1];

[~,idx] = sort(abs(a));

result = a(idx)

result =
            1         -1.1           -2            3
```

Comment: How do I change your code if I want to sort a matrix (and not a vector) in absolute values?